# Cannot reach RESTful get request

Tags: java, rest

I'm new to this but I'm trying to make a web service in Java but when I try to reach any of the methods with the web service it gives me a 404 error

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Start</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mycompany.lecture.LectureServices</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Start</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

and This is my web service LectureServices.java:

```
package com.mycompany.lecture;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/services")
public class LectureServices {

    @GET
    @Path("/sayhello")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String ViewAll() {
        return "Hello im here";
    }
}
```

I'm testing with Postman through this link http://localhost:8084/Lecture/app/services/sayhello its giving me 404 error but http://localhost:8084/Lecture/ is viewing my index.html

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/

Comment: Your index.html has nothing to do with the restful servlet.

Comment: Try removing the `'app'` from your url, i.e. http://localhost:8084/Lecture/services/sayhello